# Не могу спарсить таблицу selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не могу спарсить таблицу selenium python

```
import xlsxwriter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import openpyxl
path = './krla.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
element_list = []

binary_yandex_driver_file = r'yandexdriver.exe' # path to YandexDriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

service = ChromeService(executable_path=binary_yandex_driver_file)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
try:
    kromina = driver.get('https://www.elibrary.ru/author_items.asp?authorid=1004333&pubrole=100&show_refs=1&show_option=0')
    time.sleep(15)
    #print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[2]/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/span"))
    year = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'hdr_years').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    year2023 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'years_2023').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    poisk = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[2]/table[12]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/div').click()
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(5)

    table_rows = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr"))
    print(table_rows)
    time.sleep(5)
    table_columns = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr/td"))
    print(table_rows)
    time.sleep(5)
    for r in range(2, table_rows+1):
        for c in range(1, table_columns):
            table_values = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]").text
            sh1=wb.active
            print(table_values)
            sh1.cell(row=r, column=c).value = table_values
            time.sleep(5)
    wb.save(path)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\New\Desktop\123.py", line 42, in <module>
    table_values = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"]").text
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 738, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.972); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
```

Comment: Переходили по рекомендуемой ссылке в конце ошибки? Что предприняли?

Comment: @СергейКох Такого исключения элемента нет
Элемент не может быть найден в тот самый момент, когда вы пытались его найти.

Вероятная причина
Вы ищете элемент не в том месте (возможно, предыдущее действие было неудачным).
Вы ищете элемент в неподходящее время (элемент еще не появился в DOM)
Локатор изменился с тех пор, как вы написали код
Возможные решения
Убедитесь, что вы находитесь на странице, на которой ожидаете оказаться, и что предыдущие действия в вашем коде выполнены правильно
Убедитесь, что вы используете правильную стратегию ожидания

Comment: @СергейКох ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
kromina = driver.get('https://www.elibrary.ru/author_items.asp?authorid=1004333&pubrole=100&show_refs=1&show_option=0')
time.sleep(5)
year = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'hdr_years').click()
time.sleep(3)
year2023 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'years_2023').click()
time.sleep(3)
poisk = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[2]/table[12]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
time.sleep(3)

# soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
# titles = soup.find(id='restab').find_all('tr', id=True)
# for r in titles:
#     g = r.find_all('td')
#     print([x.text for x in g])

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

table_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='restab']/tbody/tr")[3:]
for i_row, r in enumerate(table_rows, 2):
    c = r.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    for i_col, td in enumerate(c, 1):
        sheet.cell(row=i_row, column=i_col, value=td.text)

workbook.save('my_excel_file.xlsx')
driver.close()
```